# How do I use $addToSet with objects in mongodb?

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, object, set

I want to push only unique objects into an array with `$addToSet`.

My `userSchema` has a field `bankDetails` which should take an array of objects:

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    bankDetails: [
      {
        cardHolder: String,
        cardNumber: String,
        expiry: String,
        cvc: String,
        cardBrand: String,
      },
    ]
  }
)
```

I am updating the schema using the following controller function:

```
exports.createPayment = async (req, res) => {
  const { user, cardHolder, cardNumber, expiry, cvc, cardBrand } = req.body
  const saveDetails = await User.findByIdAndUpdate(
    { _id: user._id },
    $addToSet: {
      bankDetails: {
        cardHolder,
        cardNumber,
        expiry,
        cvc,
        cardBrand,
      },
    },
    { new: true }
  ).exec();
  res.json(saveDetails);
}
```

The data is saving correctly but Mongo auto generates an `_id` field every time so technically none of the objects are unique and the objects are repeatedly added.

Is anyone aware of a workaround for this?

Comment: All documents in mongodb have an `_id` , if you dont give one mongodb will generate one before saving the document, but this is only for the root document not the embeded ones, i think its best to give an example, give a sample document if yu want and what you want as expected output , in valid json text

Comment: Thanks, I have updated my question to show my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check if a bank already exists, and add it only if not present:

```
exports.createPayment = async (req, res) => {
  const { user, cardHolder, cardNumber, expiry, cvc, cardBrand } = req.body;
  const existingBank = await User.findOne({
    'bankDetails.cardHolder': cardHolder,
    'bankDetails.cardNumber': cardNumber,
    'bankDetails.expiry': expiry,
    'bankDetails.cvc': cvc,
    'bankDetails.cardBrand': cardBrand,
  });
  if (existingBank) return res.json(existingBank);
  const saveDetails = await User.findByIdAndUpdate(
    user._id,
    {
      $addToSet: {
        bankDetails: {
          cardHolder,
          cardNumber,
          expiry,
          cvc,
          cardBrand,
        },
      },
    },
    { new: true }
  ).exec();
  res.json(saveDetails);
};
```